# How to get errors of Msbuild launched by process?

Tags: c#, wpf, process, msbuild

I'm creating a small program that launches a msbuild to compile an application. I use process but I can not get the errors that are generated. If I launch the msbuild from cmd messages appear in red, I understand that these errors should be detected by the ErrorDataReceived event but it does not work

```
    process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandlerData);
    process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandlerError);
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "test.bat";
    process.Start();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();

    private void OutputHandlerError(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
    {
        log = log + outLine.Data + "\n";
        WriteInLog(log);
    }

        private void OutputHandlerData(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
    {
        if (outLine.Data != null)
        {
            if (outLine.Data.Contains("can not find"))
            {
                log = log + outLine.Data;
                WriteInLog(log);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The FileName of the process should be MSBuild.exe, not test.bat, and supply it with the compilation parameters as Arguments.

Comment: not sure what you're trying to accomplish. If all you need is a log file, then you can redirect msbuild output to a text file.

Comment: Hi, inside "test.bat" there are some cmd commands to prepare to compilation and the MSBuild command to start the compilation.

Comment: What does `process.StandardError.ReadToEnd()` return?

Comment: Take a look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/obtaining-build-logs-with-msbuild?view=vs-2017 Notice that you can direct errors to one file, warnings to another etc. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2017

Comment: Thanks @Andy, I have read the documentation. The ErrorDataReceived event is not firing when an error appears but I configured the parameters of MSBuild for change the verbose. Now I can print all sentences with OutputDataReceived  event without blocking the applicaction because appears much less information. Is not the solution that I was looking for but it works ;)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have changed the verbose of MSBuild command and now  I can print all sentences with OutputDataReceived event without blocking the applicaction because appears much less information. I also save a file with more information about the compilation.

```
MSBuild.exe -v:q -clp:ErrorsOnly;NoSummary -fl -flp:logfile=MyProjectOutput.log;verbosity=normal ..\MySolution.sln
```

-v:q --> verbose=quiet
-clp:ErrorsOnly;NoSummary --> Show only errors
-fl -flp:logfile=MyProjectOutput.log;verbosity=normal --> Creates a file called MyProjectOutput.log to save log with verbosity=normal (show errors, warnings, high-importance messages, normal-importance messages)